# Strawberry Perl: can't install Tcl module

Tags: perl, module, tcl

[image: include folder files]
[image: TclConfig.sh content]

I have installed activeTcl, it seems something wrong with my tclconfig.file

window10+ strawberry perl(v5.28.1)+activeTcl(8.6.8.0)

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
    CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.212)
    Database was generated on Sat, 26 Jan 2019 12:11:52 GMT

    Running install for module 'Tcl'
    CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
    CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.081)
    Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\V\VK\VKON\Tcl-1.27.tar.gz ok
    CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.32)
    CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.75)
    CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
    CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
    CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
    CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20181130)
    Configuring V/VK/VKON/Tcl-1.27.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
    tclsh=C:/ActiveTcl/bin/tclsh.exe
    tclConfig.sh=C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tclConfig.sh
    tcl_library=C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tcl8.6
    tcl_version=8.6
    Using config data in C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tclConfig.sh
    incpath C:\ActiveTcl\include from your tclconfig C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tclConfig.sh does not provide tcl.h at Makefile.PL line 36.
    No 'Makefile' created  VKON/Tcl-1.27.tar.gz
      C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
    Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Tcl'.
```

Comment: Welcome! What is the directory content at `C:\ActiveTcl\include`? Can you post the content of `tclConfig.sh` (using some external paste bin pls.)?

Comment: `incpath C:\ActiveTcl\include from your tclconfig C:/ActiveTcl/lib/tclConfig.sh does not provide tcl.h at Makefile.PL line 36.` being the important bit. It can't find the TCL header files needed to build the TCL library.

Comment: attached picture shown include folder, and tclconfig.sh content

Comment: Is there a more complete log of what was actually tested? Right now, it's in “Computer Says No!” mode and that's impossible for some of us to help out with…

Comment: Mmmh. Your printout of `tclConfig.sh` does not seem to be accurate, it documents `TCL_INCLUDE_SPEC` with a directory prefix `C:\TEMP\ActiveTcl\include\...` ... which is not what you show us in the make log: `C:\ActiveTcl\include`.

Comment: `C:\TEMP\ActiveTcl\include\...` this is original path after ActiveTcl install in tclConfig.sh file，since I don't know how to run install script as above picture shown, I changed the path to `C:\ActiveTcl\include` manually.

Comment: I encountered this issue in ActiveTcl 8.6.9.8609.2 (5ccbd9ac8) as well, and have reported it to the ActiveTcl mailing list. Note to asker: please copy the relevant contents of tclConfig.sh rather than using a screenshot; doing so would probably make it much easier for search engine users to find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

manually change the below path in tclConfig.sh file,

```
TCL_LIB_SPEC='-TC:\ActiveTcl\lib\tcl86t.lib'
TCL_INCLUDE_SPEC='-IC:\ActiveTcl\include'
```

Comment: I don't know why this two path needed to be modified manually, and how to run the install script as described in tclConfig.sh file. but after change the two paths, Cpan Tcl works fine

Comment: well, hard to tell without providing more details to us. Seems like the installer failed to complete fully? How did you exactly obtain ActiveTcl? Back in the days, this was a sign of using the ActiveTcl archive release (*.zip; which is not available anymore IIRC) and not running `install.bat` or similar.

Comment: download the exe file from ActiveTcl website. and installed 
'ActiveTcl-8.6.8.0-MSWin32-x64.exe' without any Error
https://www.activestate.com/products/activetcl/